Ghost overflow-wrap appearing
I have a P element within a narrow DIV. When I view the HTML on my local machine the long words (words longer than the DIV's width) get "broken" ie wrap onto a new line. When I check the developer console I note that there's some grayed CSS associated with the P reads
overflow-wrap: break-word;

The funny thing is that the CSS is not in any file nor was it added by JavaScript.
Anyhow on the server the long words don't wrap and there's no associated CSS. I don't understand why it appears in one place and not another and, if I want the words to break, should I code the CSS in?

Some more info:
On my local machine the console shows that the DIV has this CSS
div[Attributes Style] {
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;
}

I've not set this CSS, and the console shows it ghosted ie gray in color.
When I use the console to examine the file on the server this CSS does not exist.

Your question is a little confusing. Can you give more information about the context?

div[Attributes Style] means these have been set as inline styles. If not in the HTML initially already, then I don't see what else it could have been, other than some JavaScript.

I haven't set any style inline, with code, or in an external CSS file that has anything to do with overflow-wrap. Also div[Attributes Style] is not a valid CSS selector so I don't know how Chrome is using it.
